# IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

i get list index out of range error for `isbn = book[0]['isbn']` and `book1 = book[0]`

```
@app.route("/book", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def book():
  if request.method == "POST":
    id_books = request.args.get("id_books")
    book = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE id_books = :id_books", {"id_books": id_books}).fetchall()
    isbn = book[0]['isbn']
    global book1
    book1 = book[0]
    res = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json", params={"key": goodreads_key, "isbns": isbn})
    id_books = book[0]["id_books"]
    reviews = db.execute("SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE id_books = :id_books", {"id_books": id_books}).fetchall()
    names = []
    for review in reviews:
      user_id = review["user_id"]
      username =db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id_books = :id_books", {"id_books": user_id}).fetcone()["username"]
      names.append(username)
      print(reviews)
    return render_template("book.html", book=book[0], review=res.json()["books"][0], reviews=reviews, names=names)
```

Comment: Index out of range means you have no index `0` in the `book` list. This means your database returned no books.

Can you run your sql query in your db manager, and see if it's correct? Do you have data in your database?

Comment: Try printing isbn and book before subscripting them.

Comment: Also, you should have some validation here. If you expect an ISBN id, it's possible that the book the user is querying is not in your database. In which case, you will also get the `index out of range` error. You should make sure the database is returning at least one book before trying to process said books.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily name my variable `book` the same as the function in which it resides. Have you checked how many results come back from your DB query? Are you sure you are getting any results?

Comment: If `book[0]` is out of range, that means `book` is an empty list, which means your sql query found no matching records.

Comment: Thx you all , problem solved!

Comment: Is this program a flask program ?